# Can I turn off memory compression for one specific app?

Tags: memory, java, compression, matlab

I am using MATLAB on my Mac. Well, MATLAB is running well but not fast -- while there are plenty of free memory, my Mac still compresses MATLAB's memory - from ~2GB to ~600MB -- not to mention the Java VM overhead on which MATLAB is running.

I was wondering if there's any Terminal command I can use to turn off memory compression for this specific app, just like the OS won't compress `kernel_task`. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to? Is it running slowly? And are you sure it's the compressed memory?

Comment: @seaturtle I think MATLAB is not running at its full potential since it is wasting too much time accessing the variables stored and compressed on memory. And oddly enough, the compression ratio of MATLAB is way much higher than most other apps...

Comment: Hm. Well, I don't know how to stop the compression. Out of curiosity, how did you find out that it was slow accessing variables? LLDB?

Comment: @seaturtle I think it is because when running a live script, the cpu usage is not close to 100%, while it used to be ~130%. And I’m not running other apps.

Comment: Well, just because it's not a CPU problem doesn't mean it's a memory problem, it could also be I/O or even your GPU. (: And here's the important thing – does it _feel_ too slow?

Comment: @seaturtle GPU? That is actually quite insightful. I do find CUDA has not supported High Sierra yet — although my script is not using GPU, the OS always switches to high perf. graphics card when MATLAB is running. Is this a Java thing? (I rarely use java apps) Perhaps I/O response time is affecting MATLAB performance as well, but possibly not much.

Comment: Some apps use the GPU to do general-purpose computation. I wouldn't be surprised if MATLAB does this. (GPUs are _great_ at parallel computation.)

Comment: @seaturtle thank you for the heads up! I am starting to try to get my scripts running on GPU these days. I believe I’ll find out more details about it.

Comment: FWIW, I have the same problem in Blender when tracking VFX - I have 64 GiB RAM and Blender is the _only_ app running. It works fine until it gets to ~40 GiB memory used, and then OSX begins compressing (I can see it in my iStat Menu charts) and it gets laggy when I seek back and forth in my 4k video. There is ZERO swap in use, and >20 GiB RAM free according to iStat menus. It's the ONLY proper app running (I don't count finder, iStat Menus, and other "constants"). So I for one believe memory compression IS a proximate cause.